# Excel VBA Appointments to Outlook - User-Defined Type Error

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I found the great VBA code below here on stackoverflow and when I first included it in a test workbook, it worked great. I then put the same code into the workbook I want to ultimately be using this code from and on running the module received this error:

> "Compile Error: User-defined type not defined"

I haven't been able to determine why I am receiving this error. The debugger tells me the following line is the issue:

> Dim oNameSpace As Namespace

```
 Sub Create_Outlook_3()

Dim oApp As Object
Dim oNameSpace As Namespace
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Set wsSrc = Sheets("OutlookCalExport")
' Start looping at row 3 (first two rows are for readability)
r = 3
' Do/while set condition
Do Until Trim(wsSrc.Cells(r, 1).Value) = ""

' Create the Outlook session
Set oApp = New Outlook.Application
' Set the namespace
Set oNameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
' Set the folder the appointment will be created in.
Set oFolder = oNameSpace.GetFolderFromID("000000002779752072EF5A42849125C847A02A8AE2800000").Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
' Set with block for the appointment configuration loop

    With oFolder
   ' Set Subject line of event
    .Subject = wsSrc.Cells(r, 1).Value & " " & wsSrc.Cells(r, 2).Value
   ' Set start time
    .Start = DateValue(wsSrc.Cells(r, 3)) + wsSrc.Cells(r, 8).Value
   ' Set end time
    .End = DateValue(wsSrc.Cells(r, 3)) + wsSrc.Cells(r, 9).Value
   ' Turn reminders off
    .ReminderSet = False
   ' Set busy status to free
    .BusyStatus = 0
   ' Have the body of the event read as the decription from the leave form in Viewpoint
    .Body = wsSrc.Cells(r, 4).Value
   ' Save event in owners calendar
    .Save
   ' End with block
    End With
   ' Move to next row
    r = r + 1
   ' Repeat do/while loop until condition is no longer valid
Loop

End Sub
```

I appreciate any help you all might be able to provide!

Comment: `NameSpace` is an Outlook data type.  You need a reference to the Outlook Object Model if you want it to be recognised. Click Tools then References. Scroll down to "Microsoft Outlook n.nn Object Model" and tick it. The value of n.nn will depend on the version of Office you are using.